# Views as definition list?

Tags: 7, views, theming

Is there a way to output the content of a view as a definition list?
Example:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Nodes title</dt>
  <dd>Nodes content</dd>
  <dt>Another nodes title</dt>
  <dd>Another nodes content</dd>
</dl>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a new template for how the Views row style works for your View: [Views 2 theming](http://drupal.org/node/352970).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this using [Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews), which allows you to define the markup that is output by Views.

Comment: Rockin'. Doing this with semantic views is actually quite easy.